# String Manipulation of All Elements of an Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to isolate a substring of each string element of an array such that it is the string until the last period.  For example I would want to have:

```
input = 'A.01.0'
output = 'A.01'
```

or

```
input = 'A.0'
output = 'A'
```

And I want to do this for all elements of an array.

Comment: This sounds like homework. How about posting what you've got so far and what specifically you're stuck on. Strings have two functions 'split' and 'join' which you'll find useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some rsplit magic:

```
x=["123","456.678","abc.def.ghi"]
[y.rsplit(".",1)[0] for y in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to produce the wanted output format. You need to alter this to suit your needs.

```
output = input[:input.rindex('.')]
```

For the entire array:

```
arr = ['A.01.0', 'A.0']
arr = [x[:x.rindex('.')] for x in arr]
```

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
>>> i = ['A.01.0', 'A.0']
>>> [x[:x.rfind('.')] for x in i]
['A.01', 'A']
```

Comment: `rfind` returns `-1` if the character is not found, so `"abc"[:"abc".rfind('.')]` will become `"ab"` and not `"abc"`.  That's why rsplit is more appropriate here.